# How to get a login cookie with dynamic names ?

Tags: wordpress, cookies

i use WordPress CMS for my education project. I also want to write a plugin about caching pages and faster pages.. I need to get the user logged_in cookiee name and value ? is that possible ?

Because WordPress create a hashed cookie name when user logged in;

Image :

[image]

Now how can i check this cookie is created or not ?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use logged user informations without cookies.

Comment: Fatih, infact, i should check if user logged in / or not, with cookie i really want to get this.

Comment: you can create function, it will control all cookies with foreach. ex: `foreach ($_COOKIE as $key=>$val)` and check its names. if contain cookie name **wordpress_logged_in_** return true, else return false.

Comment: @FatihSARI i 'll try , thanks about the idea.